# Как вывести изображение выбранного элемента в модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести изображение карточки товара в модальное окно?
Название из карточки удалось вывести в Input модального окна, таким образом:

```js
$('#applicationsection .element .button, #superoffer .button, #specialoffers .button, #actions .button').click(function() {
  var theme = $(this).data('theme');
  $('#themeInput').val(theme);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mix category3">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="element-inner">
      <div class="img-wrapper text-center relative">
        <a href="images/gallery/tulpan1.jpg" class="lightgallery-link absolute" data-sub-html="Букет тюльпанов #1011"></a>
        <img src="images/gallery/tulpan1-thumb.png" alt="product1" />
      </div>
      <div class="element-content">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
              Букет тюльпанов #1011
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="push10"></div>
        <span class="old-price strike">1 300 руб.</span> <span class="price bold f26 green">800 руб.</span>
        <div class="push10"></div>
        <a href="#application" class="button min fancyboxModal" data-theme="Букет тюльпанов #1011">Заказать</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Модальное окно:-->

<div class="modal" id="application">
  <div class="title-h2 green">Оформление заявки</div>
  <div class="push10"></div>
  <div class="rf">
    <form name="form-application">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="service_name" id="themeInput" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="fio" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control tel required" placeholder="Телефон *" />
      </div>
      <p><span class="red">*</span> <span class="f12">- поля, обязательные для заполнения</span></p>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" class="button btn feedback min" value="Отправить" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так — пройтись по DOM вверх к корневому блоку `.element`, найти в нем блок `.image-wrapper`, в нем `img` и взять значение его атрибута `src`, а затем полученное значение вставить в заранее заготовленный тег внутри модального окна.

```js
$('#applicationsection .element .button, #superoffer .button, #specialoffers .button, #actions .button').click(function() {
  var theme = $(this).data('theme'),
      imageSource = $(this).closest('.image-wrapper').find('img').attr('src');

  $('#themeInput').val(theme);

  $('#product-image').attr('src', imageSource);
});
```

```html
<form name="form-application">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="service_name" id="themeInput" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="fio" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <img id="product-image" src="" alt="" class="form-image" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control tel required" placeholder="Телефон *" />
  </div>
  <p><span class="red">*</span> <span class="f12">- поля, обязательные для заполнения</span></p>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" class="button btn feedback min" value="Отправить" />
  </div>
</form>
```